# Android Alarm manager fires multiple time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My Alarm manager fires multiple times in a day. I want to fire it only once in a day @ 8.00 am.

Here is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    firingCal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    if(firingCal.getTimeInMillis()>=currentCal.getTimeInMillis()){
        //set from today
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }else{
        //set for next day
        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: In your code there is nothing problem can you please tell  the time when it is fire in days ??
before installing the application please remove the first one and after install and after test it with manually change time.

Comment: In android 4.0 it fires at mid night not at exact time and with 2.3 and lower it fires twice or thrice in a day.